# What does だって mean in this sentence?

Tags: translation, meaning

> 大界王神様{だいかいおうしんさま} の弟子{でし}のままでいれば。。。私だって復活{ふっかつ}ﾊﾟワーを使えた{つかえた}んだ。

NOTE: The character talking was a disciple of the daikaioushin.

What is the だって doing in this sentence and how should I be translating or understanding it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

だって =  でも ,  "even"

This sentence would appear to mean literally "So long as I continued to be in the condition of a disciple of Daikai-oshinsama . . . even I was able to use the power of  revival/resurrection". Less literally "Even I, so long as I remained a disciple of Daikai-oshinsama, retained the power of resurrection".

Note that while である= "is", でいる= "continues to be", "remains".